# Spring project can't read icons from jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, spring, jquery-ui

In my spring project, which use the template "Dynamic Web Project" from Eclipse, I am using both bootstrap and jquery-ui to create the views. I placed both in the folder WebContent of my project.

I include the necessary files from this libraries this way:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/css/bootstrap/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/starter-template.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/grid.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/signin.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/table.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/responsible_table.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and mapped them in my class WebAppConfig.java in this way:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass=true)
@ComponentScan(value="com.horariolivre")
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/bootstrap/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/extras/**").addResourceLocations("/extras/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/jquery/**").addResourceLocations("/jquery/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Which is working partially, since the WebApp can't read the icons from jquery-ui, causing glitches in the display of some widgets I use in my views, like the jquery-ui dialog, which don't show the close button properly.

Anyone have a idea why this happening and how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this is your project: https://github.com/klebermo/maven_example/ :)

The problem:

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template --><link href="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/css/bootstrap/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your path is wrong -

```
value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/css/bootstrap/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"
```

It should be -

```
value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jquery/css/ui-lignhtess/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"
```

In case it slipped, you are also referencing both the development AND the minified versions of the same stylesheet.

Comment: I just checked your github and to be honest, I have no idea.  If jQuery is loading and images are NOT appearing, it is most likely either:

a) a path issue - images aren't found where your CSS specifies; or
b) a server issue where it won't serve up the images due to htaccess or whatever.

Suggestion: implement jQuery in a **standard** directory structure and see if it works.